# NSURLConnection Authentication Issue

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsurlconnection

I have a bit of code for sending/receiving data from a webpage that works ~90% of the time.  However the ~10% of the time it doesn't really bothers me, and I can't understand what's going on because the code isn't changing, and I have a similar android implementation that works flawlessly.  Here's what I have.

```
- (NSString*) postData:(NSString*) url params:(NSString*) params
{
    NSURL* urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[urlRequest standardizedURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0f];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSError* err = nil;

    NSData* responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&err];

    if (!err) {
        return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (NSString*) getData:(NSString*) url
{
    NSURL* urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[urlRequest standardizedURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10];

    NSError* err = nil;

    NSData* responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&err];

    if (!err) {
        return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];;
    }

    return nil;

}
```

I call getData to make the initial connection to the website.  It has some information I parse out (two security tokens to send in when I send postData) and then send the data through the POST request.  This first part always works everytime.  However I then send another POST request to change pages again (after parsing out any new security tokens), and this is the part that fails ~10% of the time.  By fail, I mean the website responds that my session has been compromised.  I know this message happens if the security tokens are invalid, but I've checked those over and over and over and everytime they're fine.  My theory is that I'm loosing cookie information, but from what I understand NSURLConnection should store the cookie information based on domain.
If I open a browser and go to the page, then delete the only cookie that is stored however, it takes me back to the login page (like expected) and doesn't give me the error message about my session being corrupted.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just a guess.. try using the request type as Asynchronous! might work!

Comment: I can try @Harsh, but any reason why asynchronous work over synchronous?